# how can i set header templete in pivot item at run time

Tags: windows-phone

actually i want to set image on header of every pivot item .....at run time using a resource

```
     <UserControl x:Class="WindowsPhoneApplication7.heder"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
d:DesignHeight="18" d:DesignWidth="24" Loaded="UserControl_Loaded">

<UserControl.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="heder_image">
        <Image Source="/WindowsPhoneApplication7;component/Images/appbar.feature.settings.rest.png"></Image>
    </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

it is a resource 
now my pivot item are in another cs file

```
     heder dis =new  heder();
   pivotItem[i] = new PivotItem();
   pivotItem[i].Header = (DataTemplate)dis.Resources["heder_image"];
```

but the header templte r not set ......image r not display

Comment: Are you sure your Image Source URI is correct? What happens if you change the template to include a TextBlock instead?

Answer (score 2):

What you're doing wrong here, is that you're setting the `Header` of a `PivotItem` to a template, instead of using the [Pivot.HeaderTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.controls.pivot.headertemplate%28v=VS.92%29.aspx). That way it wouldn't be necessary to generate the items in C# either, but instead databind (via. the [Pivot.ItemsSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms593015%28vs.96%29) property) them, and do all the styling in XAML as you're meant to do.

And when that is said, using a image for a Pivot Header, should really be discouraged, as it goes against the platforms default look&feel, and thus against the platforms UI and UX guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the image's `Build Action` is set to `Content` (see properties of the file in VS2010 explorer). If the image is in the same project as the XAML page, use `"/Images/appbar.feature.settings.rest.png"` instead of `"/WindowsPhoneApplication7;component..."`.

Use this XAML snippet and set your header in XAML:

```
<controls:Pivot ItemsSource="{Binding MyObjects}" HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource heder_image}">
    <controls:Pivot.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            ...
        </DataTemplate>
    </controls:Pivot.ItemTemplate>
</controls:Pivot>
```